# My code segfaults when compiled as shared object, works fine as standalone binary

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I have a vexing C++ problem. I've got a huge, complex wedge of code which is compiled into a Linux shared object. When it goes through one specific code path, it segfaults. (Basically one of the STL iterators seems to point a few bytes to the side of where it should.) But, if I `#include` all the code into one giant source file and compile it into a stand-alone program, everything works perfectly.

How do I even *begin* to debug this? The problem appears to not be a source-level problem, but (I guess?) some kind of weird linker issue. I'm completely lost. (I thought STL was all compile-time stuff...)

In case it matters, the SO is compiled like so:

```
g++ -m64 -c -D_CONSOLE -D__UNICODE__ -fPIC -O0 -g -D_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG <name> -o <name>.o
g++ -m64 -shared -o MangoLib.so <objects...>
```

The stand-alone consists of a small driver program with a bunch of `#include` directives, built like so:

```
g++ -m64 -fPIC -O0 -g -D_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG Test.cpp -o Test
```

I don't *think* I did anything wrong here... but the SO segfaults every single time, so I guess I did? I don't know what to do now.

Comment: I would suggest adding `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and compiling everything again.  Then run both builds under valgrind.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yeah, I might have to actually go through the torturous dependency hell to try to force valgrind to work. I just hope it tells me something!

Comment: Valgrind just tells me "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)", and the same line number where the segfault happens. Do I need to pass it some options or something?

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra` finds nothing interesting.

Comment: What is the code at  the few lines around the segfault and valgrind problem report?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Basically if I do `_items.begin()->second`, GDB shows me that all the pointers in the struct have been shifted left, the byte-sized fields have been swapped around similarly... it just really sounds like a wonky pointer. It doesn't seem to matter where I put this statement; even if it's the first line, it's wonky. And yet, using the `[]` operator on the same container works fine. GO FIGURE!

Answer (score 0):

I would start to check the usage of global variables and static initializers. The order of these things happening is not well defined AFAIK. Every global variable or static initializer that more complicated than "just fill this memory with 0 bits" should be suspect. Several static initializers referencing each other is basically a no go.

Comment: And static constructor methods?

Comment: I don't think there's anything static in the entire project.